# awk extract rows with N columns

Tags: csv, awk, sed, extract, rows

I have a tsv file with different column number

```
1 123 123 a b c
1 123 b c
1 345 345 a b c
```

I would like to extract only rows with 6 columns

```
1 123 123 a b c
1 345 345 a b c
```

How I can do that in bash (awk, sed or something else) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Awk

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NF==6' file
1 123 123 a b c
1 345 345 a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, most of the existing solutions have one potential pitfall :

> ```
>     echo "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t" |
>
>     mawk '$!NF = "\n\n\t  NF == "( NF )  \
>           " :\f\b<( "( $_ )" )>\n\n"' FS='\11'
> ```

```
  NF == 6 :
              <( 1  2   3   4   5    )>
```

if the input file happens to have a trailing tab `\t`, it would still be reported by `awk` as having `NF` count of 6. whether this test case line actually has 5 columns or 6 in the logical sense is open for interpretation.

Comment: This pitfall may be avoided by first piping the file through `sed` and removing all trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @DYZ : or simply have both `NF==6  && _<$6` to confirm it’s not empty by making sure its “greater than” an undefined empty string….. or do a regex multiply of `6 == (NF *= !/\t$/)` - multiplying NF by a false condition sets it to zero, which can’t possibly be a 6

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` let `file.txt` content be

```
1   123 123 a   b   c
1   123 b   c
1   345 345 a   b   c
1   777 777 a   b   c   d
```

then

```
sed -n '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$/p' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1   123 123 a   b   c
1   345 345 a   b   c
```

Explanation: `-n` turn off default printing, sole action is to print (`p`) line matching pattern which is begin (`^`) and end (`$`) anchored consisting of 6 column of non-TABs separated by single TABs. This code does use very basic features sed but as you might observe is longer than AWK and not as easy in adjusting N.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: You can used `sed -En '/^([^\t]*\t){5}[^\t]*$/p'` instead of hard coding all those tabs combinations `sed -n '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$/p'` in GNU or BSD sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/\S+/&/6p' file
```

This will print lines with 6 or more fields.

```
sed -nE 's/\S+/&/6;T;s//&/7;t;p' file
```

This will print lines with only 6 fields.